# Fix table rows to the top of a table once they hit the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using Datatables and Datatables row grouping plugin to group my rows into a table with a height of 500px with overflow set to scroll.

My question is, how can I fix the row that is current to the top of the table as I scroll?

Fiddles:

Have this: http://jsfiddle.net/gtgzr/22/

Want this but for each row when it hits the top: http://jsfiddle.net/aVQjN/

```
<table>
<tr style="position:fixed;top:0;background:#FFF;">row1</tr>
<tr style="position:fixed;top:0;background:#FFF;">row2</tr>
```

etc.